# receive soap response array in php

Tags: php, arrays, url, soap, callback

I'm having a problem with a SOAP request.

I need to give up an url what will be the callback url if the transaction is correctly executed. The documenation says there will be a response in this url but I don't seem to find how I can extract the response in PHP.

I have tried to do a print_r of the POST en GET vars but they seem to be empty.

So I was wondering it there is somebody who can give suggestions about what I can try?

Thx
R

Comment: provide some sort of code.

Comment: How do you make the request ?

Comment: The process is as follows:
1. I request a ID and give the callback url by doing Soapclient request 
2. I call a form from a 3th party company with the id on their website and fill it in
3. Afterwards it will go to the callback url which I provided before
4. But there I don't get anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the full request body you received on your php script, use :

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You will get a string, for example the SOAP request.

Comment: So I should be able to do a echo of $request? If so, doesn't work, don't get anything